# how to seperate the configuration files of each desktop session?

Tags: kubuntu

I want to test different desktop sessions. I have the default Ubuntu session and The KDE plasma session. But, the problem is that the system settings I apply to one desktop session is get affected in the other desktop sesion.

my question :

**Is there any way to separate these two desktop sessions configuration files so that one's  system settings does not affect the other system settings...**

I have attached the screenshot.

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtGW6.png

Comment: I'm a lover of multiple desktops installed on my systems, but as its a single system, to me it makes sense that if I make changes in one of my desktops, I want those changes to flow into all so the current way makes sense to me (note: it depends on changes, some changes do not impact other desktops). Dual boot comes to mind as the best answer, or run other systems in a VM.. but specifying your release does help as how one desktop interacts with another varies on release (or really the software stack in use)

Comment: What is the intention of your screenshot? What do you want to demonstrate? It is normal that *system* settings affect the entire *system*. Otherwise, you could work with separate accounts, each using a different desktop to keep *user* settings on each of these desktops separate.

Comment: i was showing that i have the kde plasma and the ubuntu sessions install. But my question is can i work with **same account, but keeping user settings of each of these desktops separate.**

Comment: We don't know your release which is the first bit needed; by not knowing your software stack (release) we don't know the KDE Plasma or GNOME versions, thus specific detail of how the interact with each other so sorry we can't help you as it's too vague (no specifics).   With what you've provided it's a part-Yes, part-No.

Comment: i have ubuntu version 20.04 focal and for kde i have used the command  'sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop' to install it from the terminal of ubuntu.

I have taken the reference from the [vitux site](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-the-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) to follow same procedure for my version of ubuntu